# fail2ban ignores <HOST> IP address and bans all incoming traffic

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

I'm trying to enable fail2ban on Centos 7 with Apache.
I have an app which writes to the error log a specific string when login fails.

responds with the right IP address in the Banned IP list,

```
> fail2ban-client status appname
Status for the jail: appname
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 1
|  |- Total failed: 7
|  `- File list:    /var/log/httpd/api.appname-error.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 1
   |- Total banned: 3
   `- Banned IP list:   10.50.0.68
```

But when I look in the iptables I see it blocks all incoming traffic in line 1 which corresponds to my app, EDITED: added more detailed iptables at bottom of question

```
> iptables -L INPUT --line-numbers 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports https,http match-set f2b-appname src reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
2    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
4    INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
5    INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
6    INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
7    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
8    REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Here is my filter, /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/appname.conf:

```
[Definition]
failregex = client <HOST>(.*)fail2ban\-appname\-login\-fail
```

The jail.local is short:

```
[DEFAULT]
bantime = 1200
findtime = 3600
maxmatches = 4

[appname]
enabled  = true
filter   = appname
action   = iptables-ipset-proto6[name=appname, port="https,http", protocol=tcp]
logpath  = /var/log/httpd/api.appname-error.log
maxretry = 3
mode     = normal
backend  = auto
```

And a typical line from the apache php log file:

```
[Sun Nov 26 10:22:31.255875 2023] [php7:notice] [pid 1837] [client 10.50.0.68:36530] fail2ban-appname-login-fail
```

A more detailed iptables output:

```
> sudo iptables-save -c

# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Nov 27 07:42:05 2023
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [18229:1086560]
:INPUT ACCEPT [17668:1053268]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [10696:675656]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [10696:675656]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:POST_public - [0:0]
:POST_public_allow - [0:0]
:POST_public_deny - [0:0]
:POST_public_log - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
[18230:1087136] -A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
[18230:1087136] -A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
[18230:1087136] -A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
[10696:675656] -A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
[10696:675656] -A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_direct
[10696:675656] -A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
[10696:675656] -A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_ZONES
[2972:212273] -A POSTROUTING_ZONES -o eth0 -g POST_public
[7724:463383] -A POSTROUTING_ZONES -g POST_public
[10696:675656] -A POST_public -j POST_public_log
[10696:675656] -A POST_public -j POST_public_deny
[10696:675656] -A POST_public -j POST_public_allow
[18229:1086560] -A PREROUTING_ZONES -i eth0 -g PRE_public
[1:576] -A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
[18230:1087136] -A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
[18230:1087136] -A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
[18230:1087136] -A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Nov 27 07:42:05 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Nov 27 07:42:05 2023
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [315975:53668565]
:INPUT ACCEPT [315975:53668565]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [301701:219207592]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [301701:219207592]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:POSTROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
[315976:53669141] -A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
[315976:53669141] -A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
[315976:53669141] -A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
[315975:53668565] -A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
[0:0] -A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
[301701:219207592] -A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
[301701:219207592] -A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_direct
[170984:20172057] -A PREROUTING_ZONES -i eth0 -g PRE_public
[144992:33497084] -A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
[315976:53669141] -A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
[315976:53669141] -A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
[315976:53669141] -A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Nov 27 07:42:05 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Nov 27 07:42:05 2023
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [315132:53613699]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [301701:219207592]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
[315132:53613699] -A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
[0:0] -A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
[301701:219207592] -A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Nov 27 07:42:05 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Nov 27 07:42:05 2023
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [315975:53668565]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [301701:219207592]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:PREROUTING_direct - [0:0]
:PRE_public - [0:0]
:PRE_public_allow - [0:0]
:PRE_public_deny - [0:0]
:PRE_public_log - [0:0]
[315976:53669141] -A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
[315976:53669141] -A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
[315976:53669141] -A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
[301701:219207592] -A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
[170984:20172057] -A PREROUTING_ZONES -i eth0 -g PRE_public
[144992:33497084] -A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
[315976:53669141] -A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
[315976:53669141] -A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
[315976:53669141] -A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Nov 27 07:42:05 2023
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Nov 27 07:42:05 2023
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [132432:168012162]
:FORWARD_IN_ZONES - [0:0]
:FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:FORWARD_OUT_ZONES - [0:0]
:FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:FORWARD_direct - [0:0]
:FWDI_public - [0:0]
:FWDI_public_allow - [0:0]
:FWDI_public_deny - [0:0]
:FWDI_public_log - [0:0]
:FWDO_public - [0:0]
:FWDO_public_allow - [0:0]
:FWDO_public_deny - [0:0]
:FWDO_public_log - [0:0]
:INPUT_ZONES - [0:0]
:INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE - [0:0]
:INPUT_direct - [0:0]
:IN_public - [0:0]
:IN_public_allow - [0:0]
:IN_public_deny - [0:0]
:IN_public_log - [0:0]
:OUTPUT_direct - [0:0]
[459:26548] -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 443,80 -m set --match-set f2b-appname src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
[289740:52097048] -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[7724:463383] -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
[17676:1053754] -A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
[17676:1053754] -A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
[17676:1053754] -A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
[8:486] -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
[0:0] -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
[0:0] -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
[0:0] -A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
[0:0] -A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES
[0:0] -A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
[0:0] -A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
[0:0] -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
[0:0] -A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
[144991:33496508] -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
[156710:185711084] -A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
[0:0] -A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -i eth0 -g FWDI_public
[0:0] -A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -g FWDI_public
[0:0] -A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -o eth0 -g FWDO_public
[0:0] -A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -g FWDO_public
[0:0] -A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_log
[0:0] -A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_deny
[0:0] -A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_allow
[0:0] -A FWDI_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_log
[0:0] -A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_deny
[0:0] -A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_allow
[17676:1053754] -A INPUT_ZONES -i eth0 -g IN_public
[0:0] -A INPUT_ZONES -g IN_public
[17676:1053754] -A IN_public -j IN_public_log
[17676:1053754] -A IN_public -j IN_public_deny
[17676:1053754] -A IN_public -j IN_public_allow
[0:0] -A IN_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
[11:660] -A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
[17651:1052260] -A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
[6:348] -A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Nov 27 07:42:05 2023
```

I was expecting the IP address to appear in the "source" of the iptables -L INPUT --line-numbers and was surprised to see "anywhere".

I don't understand, if fail2ban shows my IP address in the banned IP list, why doesn't it use only that IP address in the iptables?

How can I diagnose or correct this?

Thanks you!

Comment: Use `iptables-save -c` (or just `iptables -S INPUT`) instead of `iptables -L INPUT --line-numbers ` and this will become clearer.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @A.B, I used the commands you suggested but didn't understand how this makes the problem clearer. Can you please elaborate? I don't have much experience with iptables or fail2ban.

Comment: `iptables -L` is not easily usable (by me anyway). So right now, I can't easily read the ruleset until the question is edited.

Comment: I edited the question and added the result of `iptables-save -c` at the bottom of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

> ```
> 1    REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports https,http match-set f2b-appname src reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
> ```

is equivalent to:

> ```
> [459:26548] -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 443,80 -m set --match-set f2b-appname src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
> ```

If all the *matches* evaluate to true, then the *target* rule (introduced with `-j`) is performed. If any *match* evaluates to false, this stop the rule's processing before reaching the target rule, continuing to the next rule.

Having an additional condition such as: "*and also* match any IP source address" which would be `-s 0.0.0.0/0` or as "*and also* match any IP destination address" (`-d 0.0.0.0/0`) which are always true, doesn't change the outcome (with logical reasoning: (x AND true) <=> x). That's so common that although *iptables* (when it was still `iptables-legacy`) used to always store such source and destination information even with 0.0.0.0/0, it's not displayed back in ruleset outputs intended to be reproducible (`iptables-save` or `iptables -S`) but is still displayed as `anywhere` with `iptables -L` because there's a fixed column for such information anyway.

---

What matters here is [ipset](https://ipset.netfilter.org/) seen in fail2ban's configuration:

> ```
> action   = iptables-ipset-proto6[name=appname, port="https,http", protocol=tcp]
> logpath  = /var/log/httpd/api.appname-error.log
> ```

which add IP addresses retrieved from logs (when conditions for such logs apply etc., usually errors)...

... and the associated [`-m set`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#set) match module in *iptables*' rule. This rule tells that for incoming destination TCP ports 443 or 80 (else it won't go further) it will do a lookup for the source address in the *ipset* set `f2b-appname` and will evaluate to true if found, leading to the terminal (no further processing) [`REJECT`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#REJECT_(IPv4-specific)) target: the ban, or else continue to the next rule in the ruleset.

That means fail2ban uses the command [`ipset`](https://ipset.netfilter.org/ipset.man.html) to add IP entries to an *IP set*, which can then be checked (during packet path) by *iptables* which will react by rejecting any match.

So to check what has been added run:

```
ipset list
```

or more precisely in case there were others:

```
ipset list f2b-appname
```

which should end with something similar to:

```
Number of entries: 1
Members:
10.50.0.68
```

Notes:

- `iptables-ipset-proto6` despite its name handles both IPv4 and IPv6 (by checking `/etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables-ipset-proto6.conf` -> `iptables-ipset.conf` which handles differently each protocol)
- `ipset` accepts sub-commands starting with or without `--` for historical reasons.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I can see the IP list which are blocked and now I can see it is working as expected and not blocking all IP addresses.